# "Had not being able" or "not having been able"?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

I'm writing an apology letter for missed class. Which of the following should I use?

> - I had not being able to attend the class.
> - I not having been able to attend the class.

If both are ungrammatical, is there any other way to express this?

When I searched for answers, I got more confused. I couldn't find any legitimate solution, and I'm not sure if the sources can be trusted or not. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The first one is ungrammatical, and the second one can only work as a (borderline ungrammatical) dependent clause.

Comment: @ЯegDwight Thank you. Is there any other way for expressing the situation.

Comment: A native speaker would say "I was not able to attend the class".

Comment: Is it okay if I write it in a letter for class teacher or principal.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a letter, and you missed a single class, use:

> I'm sorry I was not able to attend class.

If you missed a series of classes, and you have not been back to class yet, and you want to allude to the ongoing practice of missing class, use:

> I'm sorry I have not been able to attend class.

That second sentence might be better if you were unable to attend class for a more prolonged period of time. It sounds like the wording you might have been fishing for.